# Site migration - new site not seeing default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-2008-r2

So I was migrating a website from an older sql box to our new SS 2008 r2.  I copied the files into the correct folder.  turned off the service in IIS on the old box. created a new website on the new box in IIS.  The binding's are correct.  The site worked on the old box. It's running in the ASP 4.0 app pool.  (I also tried letting it have it's own. no change.)  The Domain users have rights to the box.  So does the impersonated service account.  which is also a memeber of IIS_users.  I can ping the server. nsLookup shows the right IP address.  But when I try to browse to it, whether through IE, or even by clicking the link on the far right of the window in IIS7, "Browse Web Site", which has the correct ip, name, port 80..., I get the error

Under Construction

The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. It may be in the process of being upgraded and configured.

Except that I do have a Default.aspx page in there, and it ran fine on the old server.  I've got two other sites on this server, neither gave me any problems when I moved them.  Other than the ip they're listening for, they're set up identically.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong, or what further steps I can take to trouble shoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... Turns out we were missing an IP entry in our NIC on the virtual server... as soon as we entered it on the host, everything worked just fine.  Anyone who wants details can contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Just making sure that you checked your IIS Default Document settings.
Open IIS Manager, expand the left menu and select your web app, open Default Document. Make sure that list contains the name of your default doc and that your default doc is in the root of your application.

Comment: yes, I made sure the page was listed... it's just called Default.aspx.  I tried moving that to the top of the list- didn't think that would make a difference, and it didn't...